# Angularjs Scope method not being called by ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I am building an app.
My index.html looks like:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
 <body ng-controller='mainController'>
   <div ng-view>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**My main module js looks like:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','mycontrollers']);

myApp.directive('countTable', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {tableType:'=tableType'},
    templateUrl: '../html/table.html'
  };
});
```

**My Controller JS looks like:**

```
var mycontrollers = angular.module('mycontrollers',['dataservice']);

mycontrollers.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {

   $scope.getCellColor = function (value) {
        if(value===20){
            return 'sucess';
         }           
         else {
            return 'error';
         }
   };
});

mycontroller.controller('unitTableController', function($scope,unitdata) {
  $scope.something = {data: unitdata.getData()};
});
```

Note that the **mainController** is a parent controller. **unitTableController** inherits from the mainController.

The directive **countTable** template is loaded by the unitTableController.

The **table.html** looks like:

```
 <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in tableType.data.rows">
      <td ng-repeat="col in row track by $index" ng-class="getCellColor(col)">{{col}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

The html holding the directive looks like:

```
<div>
  <count-table table-type='something'></count-table>
</div>
```

Now the directive is printing the correct data in the form it is supposed to, but the **getCellColor()** method in the parent **mainController** is not being called.

**unitData** is a service data gets data over rest, but here it is not of concern.

I need to the set the class of the the table cell based on the condition of value in the cell.
I do not want to use the existing table/grid tools, it is a very simple table for using a tool.
Is there something I am doing wrong or is there a better way to get the class of a cell based on its values?

Maybe is there something wrong with the scope of method being called.

Please suggest.

Comment: Try just `ng-class="getCellColor(col)"`?

Comment: thnx David.. but it still does not get called in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `getCellColor` method to the directive like this:

```
<count-table table-type='tableType' 
get-cell-color='getCellColor(col)'>
</count-table>
```

The directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('countTable', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      tableType:'=tableType',
      getCellColor: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: 'table.html'
  };
});
```

The directive template looks like this:

```
 <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in tableType.data.rows">
      <td ng-repeat="col in row track by $index" ng-class="getCellColor({col: col})">{{col}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N7uwyyoz7IW0ea8NGwal?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

use getCellColor(col) instead of getCellColor({{col}})

ng-class use $scope.$eval() to evaluate an expression. you don't need to use a pair of brackets

Update:
Although you can use getCellColor(col) method to change class. It can just be evaluated once. It's suggested to set a property to each col.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But the ng-class method is still not being called.