# AngularJS: Change cell class in a dynamically generated table based on cell value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have a dynamically generated table by the following code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in tableType.data.rows track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="col in row track by $index" class={{getUnitCountCellColor(col)}}>{{col}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The data over which the table is iterated looks like:

```
[["69123", 20, 20, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 0, 20, 20, 0, 20],
 ["69121", 20, 20, 40, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 40, 20, 0, 20, 20, 0, 20],
 ["69124", 20, 20, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0],
 ["69221", 20, 20, 40, 20, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 20, 20, 20, 40]
]
```

As you can see the data is a nested array. Now I am trying to set the colour of each cell based on its value, by called the method **getUnitCountCellColor()** which is defined in the parent controller scope.

The method simply gets the value and returns the colour class based on the value as a string. (eg: danger, success)

Currently it is being called only 4 times with value **'undefined'**.

I tried to implement this with **ng-class** as:

```
<td ng-repeat="col in row track by $index" ng-class="getUnitCountCellColor(col)">{{col}}</td>
```

But then the method is not called at all.

Please help me implement this functionality, either by pointing out the error in my current code or by a different better approach.

Thanking You,

Comment: `ng-class="{getUnitCountCellColor(col)}"` maybe? 
or `class={{getUnitCountCellColor({col})}}>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ng-class` should work.

```
<td ng-repeat="col in row track by $index" ng-class='getUnitCountCellColor(col)'>{{col}}</td>
```

[Here's a demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/numajy4c6okoDNzXiWLh?p=preview) where I color all the zeros red.

### Update

So you table is in a directive, and the cell-color method is in the controller.  You can pass the `getUnitCountCellColor` function into the directive.

```
<count-table table-type='tableType' 
get-unit-count-cell-color='getUnitCountCellColor(col)'>
</count-table>
```

The scope in your directive looks like this:

```
scope: {
  tableType:'=tableType',
  getUnitCountCellColor: '&'
}
```

And the directive template looks like this:

```
<td ng-repeat="col in row track by $index" 
ng-class="getUnitCountCellColor({col: col})">{{col}}
</td>
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YDj21U220G7itkVsKEWC?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you the demo Jerrad, but in my case I have this table in a directive with its isolated scope. This directive is implemented in a view which is rendered under a controller nested under the main controller. The method that gets the color of cell is defined in the root controller scope, which is supposed to be accessible in the child controller scope. Maybe you can point me how to address the scopes in this case. A detailed question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152770/angularjs-scope-method-not-being-called-by-ng-class):

Comment: Cool... didn't know I could pass a method like that. Thanks @Jerrad that works awesome...!!